# Array of methods

Tags: android, arrays, random, methods

I am trying to randomly call methods to make it use a different animation every time to display a textview. I trie using an array but not sure how to implement it. My array looks like this (obviously I know it shouldn't be strings but not sure what data type or if even possible this way).

```
String [] mAnimations = {"Hinge","RollIn", "Landing",
        "BounceIn", "BounceInDown", "BounceInLeft", "BounceInRight",
        "BounceInUp", "FadeIn", "FadeInUp", "FadeInDown", "FadeInLeft",
        "FadeInRight","FlipInX", "RotateIn", "RotateInDownLeft", "RotateInDownRight",
        "RotateInUpLeft", "RotateInUpRight", "SlideInLeft", "SlideInRight",
        "SlideInUp", "SlideInDown", "ZoomIn", "ZoomInDown", "ZoomInLeft",
        "ZoomInRight", "ZoomInUp"};
```

Putting any of the correct animations by themselves it works fine (Note BounceInLeft):

```
YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceInLeft)
                    .duration(1000)
                    .playOn(textView);
```

But what I am trying to do is randomly pick an animation from the array something like this:

```
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(mAnimations.length) + 1;

            YoYo.with(Techniques.(mAnimations[n]))
                    .duration(1000)
                    .playOn(textView);
```

Thanks for your help
Nicholas

Comment: did you  got any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Best Directly Assign method based on Random numbers.Because (mAnimations[n]) value consider as String.

```
       String [] mAnimations = {"Hinge","RollIn", "Landing",
    "BounceIn", "BounceInDown", "BounceInLeft", "BounceInRight",
    "BounceInUp", "FadeIn", "FadeInUp", "FadeInDown", "FadeInLeft",
    "FadeInRight","FlipInX", "RotateIn", "RotateInDownLeft", "RotateInDownRight",
    "RotateInUpLeft", "RotateInUpRight", "SlideInLeft", "SlideInRight",
    "SlideInUp", "SlideInDown", "ZoomIn", "ZoomInDown", "ZoomInLeft",
    "ZoomInRight", "ZoomInUp"};

        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(mAnimations.length);
        if(n==0)
        {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.Hinge).duration(1000).playOn(textView);                    
        }
        if(n==1)
        {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.RollIn).duration(1000).playOn(textView);                    
        }
```